# LVM en Debian: extender carpeta /root

Tags: linux, debian, hardware

Me quede sin espacio en la carpeta /root, necesito hacer un upgrade a Debian 9. Pero debido a este problema no puedo.

Mi esta estructura de particion:

```
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                     8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                     8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                     8:5    0 931,3G  0 part 
  ├─educacion--vg-root   254:0    0   9,3G  0 lvm  /
  ├─educacion--vg-swap_1 254:1    0   7,8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─educacion--vg-home   254:2    0 914,2G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                       11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

La carpeta /root esta mapeada hacia `educacion--vg-root`.
Esta son mis particiones logicas:

```
lvmdiskscan
  /dev/educacion-vg/root   [       9,31 GiB] 
  /dev/sda1                [     243,00 MiB] 
  /dev/educacion-vg/swap_1 [       7,80 GiB] 
  /dev/educacion-vg/home   [     914,16 GiB] 
  /dev/sda5                [     931,27 GiB] LVM physical volume
  2 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume
```

Si hago un `df -h` se puede ver que el `root (/dev/dm-0)` esta lleno :

```
df -h
S.ficheros                     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/dm-0                        9,1G   8,6G   46M 100% /
udev                              10M      0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                            773M   9,1M  764M   2% /run
tmpfs                            1,9G    31M  1,9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5,0M   4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                            1,9G      0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                        236M    49M  175M  22% /boot
/dev/mapper/educacion--vg-home   900G   8,1G  846G   1% /home
tmpfs                            387M   4,0K  387M   1% /run/user/116
tmpfs                            387M   8,0K  387M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Si veo el volumen de la particion logica no hay espacio:

```
vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               educacion-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               931,27 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              238405
  Alloc PE / Size       238405 / 931,27 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0  /// aca muestra que  hay espacio 
  VG UUID               ttIQ4H-odre-GnH5-4x11-URPm-aVeK-mb0IW1
```

Veo que la particion logica `educacion--vg-home` tiene casi la totalidad del espacio fisico. ¿ Como puede achicarla y pasar espacio a hacia `educacion--vg-root` ?

Intente usar Gparted pero la particion logica esta bloqueada. 
He probado con `lvextend --resizefs -L 1.15T /dev/educacion-vg/root` pero como el VG no tiene espacio no se puede.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A ver, lo que tienes lleno no es `/root` sino `/`. Dentro de ese volumen reside casi todo... en este caso, todo lo que no tienes en `/home`.

Como `/home` tiene espacio de sobra, **lo primero que haría sería achicar esa partición dejándole unos cuantos gigas libres al final** (digamos, 25G). Esta operación es rápida porque no implica mover datos. **Este es el paso cero**.

Hecho esto, tienes dos caminos a seguir.

El primero es un poco una solución parche pero casi inmediata, que sería eliminar la partición swap y volver a crearla al final del espacio disponible (que acabas de liberar achicando `/home`). Hecho esto, tendrás 7GB libres luego de `/` y debieras poder asignárselos libremente.

Si no te deja hacerlo "en caliente" tendrías que iniciar con un pendrive booteable que tenga `lvextend` o `GPARTED`. Los de ubuntu lo traen, imagino que los de debian también.

Usando `lvextend`, redimensionar `/` hacia la derecha no implica mover datos así que es rápido e inofensivo. No estoy seguro ti Gparted puede modificar correctamente unidades dentro de un lvm.

Luego de esto, reinicias normalmente.

El segundo camino sería revisar qué es lo que ocupa más espacio dentro de `/`

```
 sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

Te diría que, generalmente, lo que más ocupa espacio es `/var`.

Como en el primer paso dejaste muchos gigas libres después de `/home` puedes crear una nueva partición en ese espacio libre:

```
 sudo lvcreate -L 20G -n var /dev/educacion-vg
```

Formatearla como ext4:

```
 sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/educacion-vg/var
```

y montarla en `/new_var`.

```
sudo mkdir /new_var
sudo mount /dev/educacion-vg/var /new_var
```

Luego copiar todo el contenido de `/var` a `/new_var`

```
sudo rsync -avzr /var/ /new_var/
```

Y montar temporalmente `/new_var/` encima de `/var`

```
sudo mount --bind /new_var /var
```

Sin embargo con esto aún no has liberado espacio en `/`. Para acceder a la carpeta física `/var` original, que ha quedado oculta con `/new_var` puedes montar `/` en un directorio, dentro del cual estará la carpeta original, de la cual puedes eliminar todo

```
sudo mkdir /original
sudo mount --bind /original /
sudo rm -rf /original/var/*
```

Con eso limpiaste el contenido de la carpeta original, liberando espacio en `/`.

En este punto `/dev/educacion-vg/var` está montado temporalmente en `/new_var` y   `/var` a su vez está temporalmente montado con `bind` sobre `/new_var`.

Para persistir todo eso, escribes

```
sudo blkid
```

Debiera aparecer el volumen `/dev/educacion-vg/var` con su respectivo UUID.

```
/dev/educacion-vg/var: UUID="920fd9f9-8854-3f97b596e95b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="84def38e-01"
```

Luego en tu `fstab` puedes hacer que la carpeta `/var` se monte en el volumen nuevo cuando reinicies.En tu fstab agregas (con el uuid que corresponda):

```
UUID=920fd9f9-8854-3f97b596e95b /var   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0  1
```

Y hecho esto, puedes reiniciar.

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por responder. ¿A que te referis con achicar al final y achicar hacia la derecha? Saludos.